# What is the difference between RTA_NETMASK and RTA_GENMASK?

Tags: networking, bsd

I'm just reading about the use of routing sockets in BSD. Apparently, when a `RTM_GET` message is sent to the kernel, the response can include *both* `RTA_NETMASK` and `RTA_GENMASK` socket address structures. But I thought a "netmask" and a "genmask" were the same thing. Is that true? What gives?